# Firebase Google sign in : This domain is not authorized to run this operation

Tags: angular, firebase, heroku, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble getting the Firebase Google sign-in to work with a custom domain.
This functionality works when running the app on **localhost**.
I have added the custom domain on the **Authorized domains** under the **Authentication** and **Sign in methods**

[image]

I have initialized the app with the below config in the app module.
[image]

What am I missing here, could it be that I have deployed the Angular app in Heroku with an Express server?
Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I did not include the Firebase config in the **environment.prod.ts** as I was building with the **--aot --prod** flags for the production build. ‍♂️